# Genetic algorithm - find max of minimized subsets

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithm

I have a combinatorial optimization problem for which I have a genetic algorithm to approximate the global minima.

Given X elements find: min f(X)

Now I want to expand the search over all possible subsets and to find the one subset where its global minimum is maximal compared to all other subsets.

X* are a subset of X, find: max min f(X*)

The example plot shows all solutions of three subsets (one for each color). The black dot indicates the highest value of all three global minima.

[image: solutions over three subsets](https://image.ibb.co/ch758k/bruteforce2.jpg)

The main problem is that evaluating the fitness between subsets runs agains the convergence of the solution within a subset. Further the solution is actually a local minimum.

How can this problem be generally described? I couldn't find a similar problem in the literature so far. For example if its solvable with a multi-object genetic algorithm.

Any hint is much appreciated.

Comment: I am curious: why would you want to find the maximal minimum? Also, how are your subsets defined and why can't you simply apply the algorithm to each and then compare the minimums?

Comment: To simplify: the elements X describes a graph and X* are the subsets of this graph. Min f(X) is the entropy of the graph. I want to find the maximum entropy over all subsets of X. I could apply the algorithm

Comment: @Pablo (end of previous comment)...to each subset and compare its minimums as you mentioned, but since there are 2^X subsets it is not applicable for larger X.

Comment: I see! It makes more sense now... unfortunately I don't think I can help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

While it may not always provide exactly the highest minima (or lowest maxima), a way to maintain local optima with genetic algorithms consists in implementing a niching method. These are ways to maintain population diversity.

For example, in [Niching Methods for Genetic Algorithms by Samir W. Mahfoud 1995](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.8270&rep=rep1&type=pdf), the following sentence can be found:

> Using constructed models of fitness sharing, this study derives lower bounds on the population size required to maintain, with probability gamma, a fixed number of desired niches.

If you know the number of niches and you implement the solution mentioned, you could theoretically end up with the local optima you are looking for.